# php preg_replace Check if second capture group contains data

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Here's my code

```
$string = preg_replace("/rad\:([0-9]+)px\;\s+\/\*\sALT\[(.+)\*\/|rad\:([0-9]+)px\;/",("$2"?"$2":"$1"),$string);
```

Basically, in the regex I've got a pipe |, and I'm searching for two patterns.
If there is a match to the first pattern (to the left of the pipe), then I want the it to be replaced with the second capturing group ($2), but if it's a match with the second pattern (to the right of the pipe), then I want it to be replaced with the first capturing group ($1);

The code I've tried doesn't work.
Is this possible at all?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have 3 matching groups a.t.m? What is the other for?

Comment: The first and second groups are the the first pattern match, and then the third is for the second part of the OR pattern. (if that makes sense? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> PHP 5.3:

```
 preg_replace_callback('..pattern...',
    function($match){return empty($match[2]) ? $match[1]:$match[2];},
    $string);
```

< PHP 5.3:

```
 function _my_func($match) {
    return empty($match[2]) ? $match[1]:$match[2];
 }
 preg_replace_callback('..pattern...',
    '_my_func',
    $string);
```

Or, en older PHP versions,( the `/e` modifier has [since 5.5 been *deprecated*](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php)).

```
preg_replace('...pattern..../e','strlen("$2") > 0?"$2":"$1"',$string);
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much. I'm using your third option.